# Regex: Match later occurrence followed by characters or return earlier?

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

What is the regex to catch a pattern, if it is followed by something? Otherwise, catch the first occurrence of the pattern.

Example

- Finds 'FL' in: The states of CA and FL (smaller) are along coasts.
- Finds 'CA' in: The states of CA and FL are along coasts.

Edit for example:

- Finds FL followed by '(smaller)'
- Finds CA because FL not followed by '(smaller)'

Comment: Can you explain this differently? I'm not following you here.

Comment: Your question and examples are not clear and need better explanation.

Comment: But how are FL and CA related? Do you just want to capture any 2 letter uppercase words?

Comment: @anubhava Yes. The example is not the real data. I will expand the pattern to suit the search string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear for me, but here an attempt, in `perl` flavour:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    chomp;
    if ( m/
            (?(?=.*\(smaller\))                 # Positive look-ahead conditional expression.
                \b([[:upper:]]+)\s+\(smaller\)  # If succeed, match previous word only in uppercase.
                    |                           # Or
                \b([[:upper:]]+)\b)             # If failed, match first word in uppercase found.
        /x ) {    
        printf qq[%s -> %s\n], $_, $1 || $2;    # $1 has first conditional, $2 the second one.
    }   
}

__DATA__
The states of CA and FL (smaller) are along coasts.
The states of CA and FL are along coasts.
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

With following output:

```
The states of CA and FL (smaller) are along coasts. -> FL
The states of CA and FL are along coasts. -> CA
```

---

**UPDATED** with the one-liner (output is the same):

```
perl -lne '
    printf qq[%s -> %s\n], $_, $1 || $2 
        if m/(?(?=.*\(smaller\))\b([[:upper:]]+)\s+\(smaller\)|\b([[:upper:]]+)\b)/
' infile
```

Comment: Can you write this in a one-line regex pattern? (Apologies - looking for php code.) It seems the answer I look for follows 'm/'. Is this the syntax for if, then, else?

Comment: @DavidC: Sorry, I didn't realize of the `php` tag. I'm not a `php` expert but I'm afraid that flavour is different and less powerful. I've updated the answer with the regexp to fit it in one line.

Comment: I've heard that. I think the look-around is the same. It's the pattern that's important. p.s. I added the php tag after your reply. :-)